# Typescript interface from array type

Tags: arrays, typescript, types, interface

I need to force an array to have a specific set of values that should be then the keys of my interface.
I can force the array with

```
type SomeProperties = ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3'];
```

but I don't know how to force an interface to have those properties. I tried something like

```
type MyInterface = {
  [key in keyof SomeProperties]: string;
}
```

but obviously the keys of an array are just numbers so my interface become

```
interface MyInterface {
  0: string;
  1: string;
  2: string;
}
```

instead of the wanted interface

```
interface MyInterface {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
  prop3: string;
}
```

Do you know if there is a way to achieve this in Typescript?

It would be useful because I need to iterate on some properties to "clone" an object and I also need to access to those properties easily.
Repeating the properties in both type and interface is a bit fragile for me.

Comment: Try changing `keyof SomeProperties` to `SomeProperties[number]`.

Comment: @jcalz It was a good idea but unfortunately it doesn't work, the IDE is hinting me properties like `length`, `at`, `charAt` and so on but not `prop1`, `prop2` or `prop3` :(

Comment: Not `keyof SomeProperties[number]`; just `SomeProperties[number]`.

Comment: @jcalz that works thank you! If you create the answer I can accept it as the best answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you note, the strings you're trying to access aren't the *keys* of `SomeProperties`, but the *elements* of `SomeProperties`.

You can use the [indexed access operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) here:  if `K` is a key (or a union of keys) of `T`, then `T[K]` is the property type (or union of property types) corresponding to accessing the `K` key(s) of `T`.

Tuples and arrays accept `number` as a key type, so you want to use `SomeProperties[number]` to give you the union `"prop1"|"prop2"|"prop3"`:

```
type SomeProperties = ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3'];

type MyInterface = {
  [K in SomeProperties[number]]: string;
}

const myInterface: MyInterface = {
  prop1: 'this',
  prop2: 'works',
  prop3: 'now'
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgBQE50q4BLCBnKAXigG0ByMdMARjIBooKqAmexyjAZjIF0BuALAAoYaEhQAsiACSAO2ARUAMwCGAY2jEA3sKh7SAaSjZZsRCiqKc+ErICuCAEaKePAFxQ8wVCYDmgoQBfYWE1OFkvKAQZeUVVDQ8pOQVldU0oHSF9KA4aDzJgAAtsPHpdfVzmfIB3OFQAa1K6cr1cznzZOGqyYUCgA)

Answer (score 6):

<s>*Worth noting: You can't iterate an tuple type in TypeScript*</s>

Actually, you can! Since TypeScript 3.1 [you can safely use tuple types in mapped types like objects](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-1/#mappable-tuple-and-array-types).

These sorts of operations can only be applied to `type`s, not `interface`s.

```
type SomeProperties = 'prop1' | 'prop2' | 'prop3';

type MyType = Record<SomeProperties, string>;

// equivalent to
// type MyType = {
//   [key in SomeProperties]: string
// }
```

Types and interface are the same from the perspective of the consumer (when you ask for a `MyType`, you don't care if it's an interface or a type, they're the same at that point)

Comment: I will change my question using type, sorry.
So do you think it's impossible to achieve what I'm asking?

Comment: I think this is a better option unless you are working on an array, e.g. for the generic:

const ATTACK = "attack";
const CARRY = "carry";
const CLAIM = "claim";
const WORK = "work";

type EnumDictionary<Enum extends string, TValue> = { [K in Enum]: TValue };

const CREEP_BODY_PART_COST: EnumDictionary<
  ATTACK | CARRY | CLAIM,
  number
> = {
  attack: 80, // OK
  carry: 50, // OK
  claim: 600, // OK
  work: 100 // FAIL
};

Comment: @DropBearDan Screeps FTW!

Answer (score 0):

Update to Madara's answer for future readers.

> These sorts of operations can only be applied to types, not
> interfaces.

I don't know since when, but nowadays you can do this with interfaces too.

```
type SomeProperties = 'prop1' | 'prop2' | 'prop3';

interface MyType extends Record<SomeProperties, string> {
   // other properties
}
```

It is equivalent to the following:

```
type SomeProperties = 'prop1' | 'prop2' | 'prop3';

type MyType = Record<SomeProperties, string>;
```