# How do I use an array of strings to be an interface's keys?

Tags: typescript, typescript3.8

Suppose I have this array of strings:

```
const claims = ['val1','val2','val3','val4', ...]
```

### How can I build an interface based on the values in `claims` like this:

```
interface Claims {
  val1: boolean
  val2: boolean
  val3: boolean
  val4: boolean
  ...
}
```

I'm using Typescript 3.7.x

---

I tried playing off of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46344193/1439748

> ```
> interface Claims{
>  [key in claims[number]]?: boolean
> }
> ```

But received these errors:

```
A computed property name in an interface must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.ts(1169)
A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.ts(2464)
The right-hand side of an 'in' expression must be of type 'any', an object type or a type parameter.ts(2361)
'number' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)
```

Comment: can you share playground reproduction link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out your code will work by making these 3 changes:

- place `as const` after you array literal so that `claims` is inferred as a (read-only) tuple
- use the (type space) `typeof` operator with `claims[number]`
- instead of an `interface` use a type alias combined with a object type literal;
  as it turns out an interface does not work whereas a object type literal will.

I ended up with the following code:

```
const claims = ['val1','val2','val3','val4'] as const;

type Claims = {
  [key in typeof claims[number]]?: boolean
}
```

Comment: How would I do this in an interface itself. If I try to add `[key in typeof claims[number]]?: boolean` inside an interface, I get a lot of errors